# In a closed system, what is the relationship, if any, between currency supply and market capitalization?

Tags: currency, monetary-policy, stock-market

Assuming:

1. A world in which the market value of publicly traded companies is known
2. Any transaction to buy or sell stock of said companies can **only** be consummated with a new currency X, which is freely tradable into and out of other, existing currencies (that is, currency X is required only as long as the transaction is in flight; the buyer trades value into X, makes the purchase, after which the seller trades out of X back into some other form of value.)
3. The total supply of currency X is fixed and known

Then:

What correlation is there, if any, between the total market cap of currency X and the total market cap of the publicly traded companies (both market caps being calculated in the same external form of value)? Put another way, what would determine the value of currency X in terms of other forms of value? The total market cap of the companies? The total of market transactions in flight at any given moment? Something else? Nothing?